# Express POST request with 2 query string parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to code my POST request (using node-fetch) with express and node.js, but I am not sure how to route two query string variables. I have built the query string already, but I cannot figure out how to handle it on the back-end.

What is supposed to happen: I am creating a To-Do List app. I have a form to create a new list. It has input for the new list name and a color for the list. I just want to be able to POST that data and put it in my oracle database.

Here is my route:

```
app.post('/api/add-list/:name&:color', api.addList);
```

Here is my add-list.js file:

```
// Use to simplify require statements
global.__root = __dirname; 
console.log(__dirname);

// DB Setup
var config = require('../config.js');
var db = require('../lib/db-lib.js');



exports.post = function(req, res) {

     console.log("adding list");

     db.auth(config.DB);

     // This is not right, I know
     var args = getQueryVariable();

     let name = req.body.name;
     let color = req.body.color;

     var args = {name:name, color:color};

     db.proc('hu_mgr.zrptodo.p_add_lists', args, function(err, rows) { return 
          res.json(rows); });
}
```

This is the error I get after trying to submit my new list.

POST http://192.168.56.101:5000/api/add-list/name=Andrew&color=purple 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Usually your route should be POST /api/add-list and you have to send body params

query/route params are useful for GET requests. for example GET /api/list/:name or GET /api/list?name=yourName&color=yourColor 

So from your client do a POST request to /api/add-list and send POST body data, then in your backend handle it like in your example above: req.body.name req.body.color

Answer (score 0):

Hi Andrew  Although you didn't say it, I'm assuming you want to create a REST API for your app. With REST APIs, the URLs are generally based on nouns, not verbs because the HTTP method will specify the action/verb. So, rather than POST to `/api/add-list`, you would POST to `/api/lists`.

Also, when doing a POST, it's more common to send the data as part of the request body rather than the URL.

As to the error you're getting, you aren't showing us the actual error, only what's displayed to the client. Try looking in the console for more details as to what's going wrong.

Also, you might find this series on creating REST APIs on Oracle Database useful:
https://jsao.io/2018/03/creating-a-rest-api-with-node-js-and-oracle-database/